# Python: Scaling all 4th dimension values in a 4d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4d numpy array with shape:

```
(5500, 350, 350, 3)
```

These represent 5500 images of size 350x350 pixels, with the 4th dimension being a number from 0 to 255 representing the RGB values of each pixel. I want to scale these to be between 0 and 1 (ie. divide by 255) for all 5500 images. How should this be done?

Comment: `input_array/255.0`?

Comment: @Divakar is completely right, I think you mixed up dimensions and content somehow: The fact that you need 3 additional dimensions to store the three colors of each pixel of all those images does not mean, that the color is hidden solely behind this 4th dimension. The whole array does not contain anything else than these numbers from 0...255, a third stands for red, a third for green and the rest for blue. So it's in fact as easy as simply dividing the whole array by 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just as simple as

```
a = np.linspace(0,1,255)
```

And just put in the value of your 4th dimession, e.g. `a[42] = 0.1653543307086614`